# Flot legendFormatter is not working with ng-click

Tags: angularjs, flot, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to create clickable legends. I am using flot chart and legendFormatter to manipulate the legends. Here is my code in js file:

```
$scope.labelFormatter = function (label, series) {
    return "<div class='col-md-12' style='font-size:12px;'><span>" + label + "</span><span ng-click=\"removeFromFunnel(" + (series.data[0][0] - 1) + ")\" class=\"criteriaClose\">✖</span></div>";
};

pageData.barChartOptions.legend = {show: true, labelFormatter: $scope.labelFormatter, noColumns: index};

$scope.removeFromFunnel = function (index) {
       if (index > -1) {
           pageData.funnel.splice(index, 1);
       }
};
```

This way, the program does not seem to recognize ng-click. I also tried to use onClick but I think the function needs to be out of scope with that way.

Why is ng-click not working? What should I use instead of it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: a html button control is taken with hiding in the button control ng-click called.Again define a javascript fuction where called the click event of the hidden button

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you. Can you be clearer please? @LDS

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="display:none"><input type="button" value="" id="rid" ng-click="removeFromFunnel()" /></div>
<div style="display:none"><input type="hiden" value="" id="hid"/></div>


The beloow is the js code
function remove(value)
{
 document.getElementById("hid").value = value;
 var btn = document.getElementById("rid");
 btn.click();
}


you can collect the value in the angular function removeFromFunnel()

$scope.removeFromFunnel()
{
var value = angular.element(document.querySelector('#hid'));
//do your work with the value 
}
```